# How to jump from one input to the next one with the same class (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, filtering

I am looking for a way to jump form a input to the next one with the same class. The inputs in a form should be chained to each other(not all but some). This can be done pretty easy it the layout was simple, but the layout can and will change so its make it hard to do something like parent() -> next(). So how to find the next input in the form/layout with the same class without going back to the first element(dont want to loop them).

Form code(example just to give you an idea)

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="chainme"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="chainme"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="chainme"/>
            <div>
                <input type="text"/>
                <input type="text" class="chainme"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please Add some html you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest means I could think of for this would be along the lines of:

```
$('form').on('keypress','input',function(e){
    var eClassName = this.className,
        index = $(this).index('.' + eClassName) + 1;
    if (e.which === 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input.' + eClassName)
            .eq(index)
            .focus();
    }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZmAEG/).

This assumes that you want to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to move to the next `input` of the same class. Also, that the element has only one class.

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @user759235: you're very welcome! But please see the amended code (in the original version I used `index()` where I should've used `eq()`, which I've just corrected). ...oops. =/

Comment: thanks, i did get an error, but the .eq() fixed it, many thanks i have learned something new today!!

Comment: Yeah; that's exactly what I was getting, I'm somewhat embarrassed it took me so long to remember that `index()` *returns the index* and doesn't *set* the index. Sigh, still running into the getter/setter problems... =)

Comment: Well we all make mistakes, that life, but the main point is that you have solved my issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `next()` lets you pass in a selector - this will restrict it to only the class you want, whilst not going back to the beginning.

Comment: `.next` will select the **next sibling** if and only if it matches the selector.

Comment: Next cant travel up the DOM. I have added an example of a layout. Thanks

Comment: Ah, didn't see that part. In that case, David's solution is good - you could even optimise it by early indexing all of the elements with that particular class and traversing the stored array.